# Xcode 6.1 upgrade - ViewController no longer conforms to protocol WKScriptMessageHandler

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webkit

I'm using the `WKScriptMessageHandler` in my iOS App to receive messages from the Webkit.  I'm using the `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol, but apparently after upgrading Xcode to the most recent 6.1 upgrade, I am now getting this error message:

```
Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'WKScriptMessageHandler'
```

Any ideas on how this should be done now? Why did Apple change this

Here is my code below:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    @IBAction func fourButton(sender: UIButton){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController!, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage!){
        println("got message: \(message.body)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The function definition has changed, remove the exclamation marks:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage)
```